# Android Out of Memory Error Drawable Animation

Tags: android, animation, memory, frame, drawable

I´m new developing, so please don´t be so hard on me if I ask a stupid question.
I´m trying to run an app with drawableIanimations, but not buttons or pop ups animations neither, I mean, an animation frame by frame from a 2 to 4 seconds video. I extract from a 2 to 4 seconds video, 10 to 30 frames per second. Some animations has the android:oneshot set to false and some set to true.
So, I´m trying to develop an app, with a RelativeLayout and an ImageView on it, then a LinearLayout with 10 Buttons to start each animation.
My app runs well at first, but sometimes it stop and I get the Out of Memory Error.
I don´t know if the structure I choose is right or I´m doing something wrong. 
Here, I give you some info about what I´m doing, for you to help me or give a good advice or put me on the right track about this app.

Images
10 animation of 4 second each. 30 images each second. 1200 images.
If I make images for each size of screen, I know I will kill the memory, so I only using images in the drawable-ldpi directory. I don´t know if its that ok.

screenOrientation="portrait" all the time.

Each image size: 135x240 21.8kb

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
tools:context="com.absolutkarlos.roccoalejandro.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageninicial" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/botonera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/startanimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/iniciar" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopanimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/stop" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button3" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button4" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button5" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button6" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button7" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button8" /> 
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/entrada07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button9" /> 
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button10" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.absolutkarlos.roccoalejandro;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
private ImageView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
        // Type casting the Image View
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada01);
        // Type casting the Animation drawable
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            }

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startanimation);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.caricias_durmiendose);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopanimation);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.caricias_volteado);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada01);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada01);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada02);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada02);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada03);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada03);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada04);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada04);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada05);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada05);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada06);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada06);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrada07);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada07);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        // Start animation when in Focus
        frameAnimation.start();
    } else {
        // stop animation when not in Focus
        frameAnimation.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Each animation list *.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada006" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada007" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada008" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada009" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada010" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada011" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada012" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada013" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada014" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada015" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada016" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada017" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada018" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada019" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/entrada020" android:duration="30" />

</animation-list>
```

I hope someone can help me or just give me an advice to go on...
Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: Do you free all of your unnecessary memory in the android application lifecycle? Or maybe you should do it after each of the animations?

Comment: How do I do that? sorry if ask a dumb question but I don´t understand how to manage the lifecycle.